# Reference mutable external webservice url in tomcat webapp

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jax-rs

I have a jax-rs webapp deployed on tomcat. The webapp references another external webservice, whose url may change due to version increment and is different on the dev environment than in production.

Now I tried different approaches to reference the current external service url but neither seems good enough:

A) I can have variables in a database table, which is different for dev/ production. On version increment, I'd need to update the urls. This works ok, but I'd rather like the variables closer with the application, if possible.

B) I can store the variables in context xml. But then I have application-specific parameters in it, which I would like to avoid. Even more, i need to restart the application or even the tomcat instance for changes to take effect. I'd like to avoid that in the production environment.

C) I can place the variables in web.xml. Then I have to update the application with a version increment of the external webservice. I could handle this if I only link to major versions of the external webservice, where endpoints may change, so updates would be seldom. But worse is, I will not have different values for dev and production, as web.xml comes with the application.

Any other ideas or suggestions, how to come around this?

Comment: And why you have different environement on developement stage than in production??!

Comment: Because in development stage external services have always the same url e.g. localhost:8080/service-x. In production environment they get the version and build number attached, e.g. localhost:8080:service-x-1.0-SNAPSHOT-xxx.

Comment: IMHO DB is the most reasonable solution

Comment: Ok. thanks for your opinion!
Are there other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I ended up with a properties file now, which I did not pack with the application but which resides on the server. So I can have different ones for development and production, where I reference the current version of an external webservice. The properties filename comes from context.xml.